# jQuery simple multiple modals on one html page

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplemodal, eric-martin-modal

I tried the simple modal of Eric martin modal plugin.
And I got a little difficulty. I did one modal on Html page but what if I want some more modals in one HTML page like I did the first one-just with different background and content?

HTML:

```
<div id='content'>

    <div id='basic-modal'>



 <a href='#' class='basic'>white whine</a>


 <div id="basic-modal-content">

 <p> text text text</p>
          </div>  
          </div>
          </div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Load dialog on page load
//$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();


    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: By the way , i know the bg is inside #simplemodal-container css file ,
but how can i change for each modal #simplemodal-container background inside the css for each modal i want to do on same html page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy for you unless you are not opening them simultaneously. Because the plugin uses `id` for it's containers and some elements in plugins. And having same id in a page will create issues in your code.

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/226/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
    <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic' />
    <div id="basic-modal-content1">Dialog 1</div>
    <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic' />
    <div id="basic-modal-content2">Dialog 2</div>
    <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic' />
    <div id="basic-modal-content3">Dialog 3</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $(this).next('div').modal();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Code is pretty much clear. For every dialog instance, there is a separate div element which  contains separate html. As far as the background is concerned, you can do it by giving CSS styles to the dialog containers.

For CSS,

This plugin provides an option for `containerId` which can be used for assigning custom Id to the container. Also you can use same ID for different CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/227/

**jQuery:**

```
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    var c =  $(this).next('div');
    var id = c.attr('id')+'_c'; // create a custom Id.
    c.modal({
        containerId:id, 
    });
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
#basic-modal-content1_c{
    background-color:green;
}
#basic-modal-content2_c{
    background-color:red;
}
#basic-modal-content3_c{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

In this way you can change the CSS. Please refer the customizable options of plugin. I am pretty sure you can use them for your purpose.

Comment: Hey , thanks on the quick answer.
I'm not opening them  simultaneously . How I change for each modal the background container?

I tried in the CSS file to play with the id #simplemodal-container background value and change it to some other background but it didn't work it changes only the background of the first modal I made. How I change the background for each modal in the CSS ?

Comment: Wow man , you saved my life. In big it works ! But if i want that it wont be inside button, but inside links like i did and with <p> content inside the modal how I do it?  you can see the first code i wrote in the question is example. Thanks

Comment: And I need the code with the X img that i had , and not just pressing escape button on keyboard for exiting the modal .

Comment: For inside links, just give the class of button to link and it will work. Actually, in your code it will have closing image. Since it was a fiddle, I didn't used the image.

Comment: And how I put text inside each modal?

Comment: Just put your content in the div whose id starts with "basic-modal-content".