# Multiple modals on same page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get multiple modals to fire on one page, while pulling up the correct content of each modal.  I am sure this has something to do with differentiating ids or classes, just cannot figure it out.  Your help is appreciated.

Here is the code to trigger the modal, I am just confused on how to make this specific to each link. JSFiddle link below

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_1');

var btn = document.getElementById("modal_1");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Content of Modal 2

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modal_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/o4vohxr4/`

Comment: The JSFiddle seems to work to me. What is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Modal 1 should open 'modal 1' & Modal 2 should open 'modal 2'  Each link is opening 'modal 2'.  I updated the naming so it makes more sense.

Comment: I only see one modal in the JSFiddle. `#modal_planting_mix`. Check your JSFiddle and please update.

Comment: my apologies, try this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fastgrowingtrees/w3bo9q29/

Comment: Again, there's only 1 modal there. `#modal_2`. `#modal_1` just contains the buttons. Are you expecting modal 1 to act like a modal? Is modal 1 suppose to open modal 2?

Comment: They should bring up different content when clicked.  I expect when I click 'Modal 1'  to bring up the content of modal 1 and when I click 'Modal 2' to bring up the content of modal 2

Comment: Maybe this might be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586148/jquery-simple-multiple-modals-on-one-html-page Also, you could consider using `data-*` attributes (e.g. `data-trigger="#modal1"`) to make your code nice and clean and include the `#id` of which modal to open. Then in your jQuery, grab the `data-trigger` attribute and open that modal instead. Can write an answer explaining this in more detail if you like

Comment: I read that post... I will review more closely, thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the proper version from your tests that works with 2 modals. In case others needs it. https://jsfiddle.net/fastgrowingtrees/w3bo9q29/13/ BIG THANKS

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your fiddle, the problem is that you are overwriting your own variables.

You use `vars` `modal`, `btn`, and `span`for both event handlers. Since modal 2 is set up later, its `modal` value is used for both buttons.

Also, `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]` will get the first `close` class element each time, which is why the `X` doesn't work on the `modal 2` since both event handlers are trying to hide modal 1.

You need to use unique variable names when they are within the same scope and remember that document level commands like `document.getElementsByClassName` will always start at the top.

Also, you assign `window.onclick` twice, with the second one overriding the first.

Here is a quick take on a minimal edit to get the functionality you want, but give some thought to better variable naming than I use here.

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modal_1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}



// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("modal_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal || event.target == modal2) {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just trying to get the basic functionality down.  This helps a bunch.

Comment: Exactly @JustinFrench !  and this can be refactored a lot, you have right now everything twice, ok only two modals, but if in the future appears 4 more, are you gonna have everything 6 times ?? no man, painful to maintain.

Somebody calling the Functions emergency number ! ;) 

Just declare a function that check the id of the modal and then show the right one !